# Android accessing content provider data from NDK / C++ side

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I'm throwing an intent to pick an image from the gallery, nothing special there.

If an image is on the file system (able to be opened as a simple file), there's no issue.

But, when I select an image from a provider:
"content://com.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5694310418485786498"

I am having trouble because I need to open the file from the provider.

How do I open the image from the NDK side through C++ code, as I can not open it as a regular file on the file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

"You cannot access features such as Services and Content Providers natively, so if you want to use them or any other framework API, you can still write JNI code to do so."

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was hoping not to get.  But I did need confirmation.